# How to resize the partition of a RAID 1 logical volume on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

Six years ago I created a RAID 1 logical volume with AMD RAIDXpert and installed Windows 7. The logical volume hosts two partitions for c: drive and d: drive.

How do I resize the partitions (to make more space for c:)?

I'm basically familiar with how partition resizing works and I used tools for that in the past. The problem is that they all see the physical disks "behind" the logical volume and won't allow me to transparently resize the respective partitions. The Windows disk manager and the partition tools see the same structure.

**Windows**
[image]

**EaseUS Partition Master**
[image]

Comment: Delete the D partition extend the C partition then create a new D partition this is the only way to achieve what you want, don't use EaseUS to do this you will break your software RAID

Comment: Even if I do that in Windows directly I'd need a way to make sure disk 0 and disk 1 are in sync, no?

Comment: Windows believes your disks are a single disk.

Comment: What makes you believe it does? I does believe that drive c:/d: are on a single disk but the disk manager can't be fooled. Are you suggesting that if I extended drive c: on disk 0 Windows would automagically resize the respective partition on disk 1?

Comment: This is the problem with screenshots that are not in english.  I can't read them properly.